# How to customize file access permissions for INI files?

Tags: advanced-installer

In AdvancedInstaller it's possible to customize file using the [Permissions Tab](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/permissions.html) of the file or folder properties dialog.
This is not available for INI files created using the [INI File Dialog](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/edit-ini-file-dialog.html).

How can I customize INI file acces permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this AI community posting](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20265) this is not directly possible. But there is a workaround to accomplish it:

In order to customize permissions for `Application Folder\myApp.ini` created using the [INI File Dialog](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/edit-ini-file-dialog.html), create a new physical file with the same name in your filesystem (e.g. `c:\installer\myApp\myApp.ini`).

In AdvancedInstaller add that file to the same folder where your `myApp.ini` already resides in: `Application Folder` in this case. Skip the INI import functionality.

Now it should look like you have two `myApp.ini` files in your `Application Folder` and you can edit all the file access permissions on the imported `myApp.ini` just like you do on any other files or folders.
These customizations will be applied to the installed `myApp.ini` on the target machine.